# Connecting to remote MS SQL database through SQLSRV driver

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to a remote ms sql db (not a localhost), but everytime it timeouts before it sucseeds...

I'm pretty sure that the problem is the $serverName variable, is there anyway to check via Plesk Parallels what is the value of that?

```
    <?php
        $serverName = "server's ip address/database name"; //serverName\instanceName
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database name", "UID"=>"DBusername", "PWD"=>"DBpassword");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn ) {
             echo "Connection established.<br />";
        }else{
             echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Open a command prompt in windows, and type in the following: `telnet ip_address 1433`. What is the result?

Comment: C:\Users\itay>telnet (IPADDRESS) 1433
Connecting To  (IPADDRESS)...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433
: Connect failed

Comment: Then there's the issue. Either A. this host doesn't accept remote connections to the SQL server, B. the SQL server isn't operating, or C. the SQL server isn't listening on the default port of 1433.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my ip address was not permitted to connect to the database, after I contancted my hosting service provider they gave me that permission and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject precise port number into ServerName like

```
<?php
  $serverName=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS,1433; //networkAddr\InstanceName,<portNum>
?>
```

Try using Ip address instead NetBios name if you do, cause ICMP protocol is usually blocked due security policy.

Also, the default port 1433 may be blocked. Should contact server administrator to provide actual connection requisits in that case.